# The Liskov substitution principle Invariance

Tags: c#, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

Could anyone explain to me why this code is not working? How is related to the LSP rule? What does Invariance mean in this context?

The example is from Adaptive code via C# book:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IDictionary<A, A> dict1 = new Dictionary<B,B>();
        IDictionary<B,B> dict2 = new Dictionary<A, A>();    
    }
}
public class A { }
public class B: A { }
```

Error Message

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<LSP.core.B, LSP.core.B>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<LSP.core.A, LSP.core.A>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
> Error    CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<LSP.core.A, LSP.core.A>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<LSP.core.B, LSP.core.B>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: @gunr2171 I have edited the question to add the error

Comment: @MindSwipe both instruction are not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple example:

```
class A { }
class B : A { }
class C : A { }

// Imagine this was allowed:
var dict1 = new Dictionary<B, B>();
IDictionary<A, A> dict2 = dict1;

// Then you did this:
var c = new C();
dict2[c] = c;

// And finally tried to do this:
B b = dict1.Keys.First(); // Breaks type safety, because First() returns a C instance
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the IDictionary is a `generic` class.

Take the following example:

```
public class A { }
public class B: A { }
```

B is a subclass of A, so this is allowed.

```
A varName = new B();
```

but when you use `varName` in code you can only access the propteries of A class

But `List<B>` is not a subclass of `List<A>`, even though `B` is a subclass of `A`.
The compiler does not check the generic parameter type for inheritance, and considers them different types.

the following is is not allowed

```
List<A> listName = new List<B>();
```

what is allowed id to use the LSP rule to fill the list

```
List<A> listName = new List<A>();
ListName.Add(new B());
```

But when you access `ListName[0]` the compiler considers the object you will get as a type `A` object.

Comment: This really just says "you can't do it" rather than explaining why.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay you are right your explanation is better using the C type makes it much more clear

Comment: It isn't COMPILING because the "type arguments" (which is different from "type parameters") define the generic type. In the context of the example code, execute something like this:
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Dictionary<A, A>).FullName);
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Dictionary<B, B>).FullName);
and see what it says. 
In short Dictionary<B,B> is not a subclass of Dictionary<A,A>.

Comment: Continuation on above comment:
LSV says: "The principle defines that objects of a superclass shall be replaceable with objects of its subclasses without breaking the application" but, the broken example is trying to replace the 
-object of a generic class (interface) with the type arguments of the superclass 
with the 
-object of a generic class with the type arguments of the subclass
It is also trying to do it in the reverse direction. None of that is what the LSV suggests.