# In C#, how can I cast an interface to an interface which extends the interface?

Tags: c#, lambda, interface, compiler-errors

I have a few interfaces:

```
    public interface ILockable
    {
        public string LockToken { get; set; }
    }

    interface ILockableSalesforceRecord : ILockable, ISalesforceRecordable
    {
    }

    public interface IServiceBusMessageReceiver
    {
        Task DoWithAsync<T>(IQueueConfig queueConfig, Func<List<ILockable>, Task<bool>> function)
            where T : ILockable;
    }
```

And I have a method with this signature:

```
private async Task<bool> WriteToSalesforceCacheAsync<T>(List<ILockableSalesforceRecord> eventBusRecords, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I would like to pass this to an concretion of the last interface in the following method:

```
        public async Task WriteToSalesforceCacheAsync<T>(IQueueConfig queueConfig, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            where T : ISalesforceRecordable
        {
            await _serviceBusQueueReceiver.DoWithAsync<T>(queueConfig, async records =>
            {
                return await WriteToSalesforceCacheAsync<T>((List<ILockableSalesforceRecord>)records, cancellationToken)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
            });
        }
```

But this fails to compile with:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0030  Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Enpal.Messaging.ILockable>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Enpal.AzureServiceBusToSfCacheTranscriber.Models.ILockableSalesforceRecord>'   Enpal.AzureServiceBusToSfCacheTranscriber   C:\projects\AzureServiceBusToSfCacheTranscriber\AzureServiceBusToSfCacheTranscriber\Helpers\RelayHelper.cs  38  Active

Is there something I can/should do to fix this?

Comment: check out this post it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67092457/the-liskov-substitution-principle-invariance/67092974#67092974

Comment: Try using `IList` instead of `List` in interfaces and cast.

Comment: But I would say that the fact you having this cast seems to mark that you are doing something wrong on design level.

Comment: You can only cast an inherited class to it base class.  Not the base class to the inherited class.  ILockable (base) and ILockableSalesforceRecord(inherited)

Comment: Remove the cast, and instead use `records.Cast<ILockableSalesforceRecord>().ToList()`, or `records.OfType<ILockableSalesforceRecord>().ToList()` if `records` possibly contains objects that don't implement `ILockableSalesforceRecord`

Comment: This looks like a List<Animal> vs. List<Lion> problem. You cannot cast a list of animals to a list of lions, even though the lion is an animal. You have to cast each element separately (see the comment from @MindSwipe)

Comment: Or in other words: a `Myclass<Derived>` simply is **not** a derived class of `MyClass<Base>`.

Comment: Cheers to all the reponses.  The reason I am _trying_ to use that particular function for that particular interface is because while the model and the function is concerned with both the service bus and Salesforce, the interface doesn't and should not know anything about Salesforce  While I can understand not every Animal is a Lion, shouldn't the derived interface extending the base interface guarantee my class has all the properties and methods to qualify as "Lionlike"?  Should it really be the compilers job to make sure I'm not doing something completely stupid or abusive with that?

Answer (score 1):

In your interface, you declare a generic parameter `T`, but don't actually use that in your arguments.

You probably meant to design it like this:

```
public interface IServiceBusMessageReceiver
{
    Task DoWithAsync<T>(IQueueConfig queueConfig, Func<List<T>, Task<bool>> function)
        where T : ILockable;
}
```

Also, with your methods `WriteToSalesforceCacheAsync`, you declare `T` again, but it looks like you are now using a specific type (namely `ILockableSalesforceRecord`), so the `T` can be dropped:

```
private async Task<bool> WriteToSalesforceCacheAsync(
    List<ILockableSalesforceRecord> eventBusRecords, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    //...
}

public async Task WriteToSalesforceCacheAsync(
    IQueueConfig queueConfig, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await _serviceBusQueueReceiver.DoWithAsync<ILockableSalesforceRecord>(queueConfig, 
    async records =>
    {
        return await WriteToSalesforceCacheAsync(records, cancellationToken)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    });
}
```

Now, because `ILockableSalesforceRecord` is supplied as the generic argument to `DoWithAsync`, `WriteToSalesforceCacheAsync` is subsequently passed a `List<ILockableSalesforceRecord>` and the code compiles: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5Bz7SS

---

As an aside, you shouldn't be relying on a specific collection type in your interface signature such as `List<T>`, as this is restrictive to clients; instead use an interface type dependent on requirements e.g. `IEnumerable<T>`, `ICollection<T>` etc.

Comment: This looks promising.  I'll try this tomorrow.  Cheers! :-)